# Passing zipped tuple into function

Tags: python, tkinter, zip, tuples

I have a Class hierarchy where I am trying to switch tkinter windows while retaining specific properties (such as window name, dimensions, resizable, etc.).  I'm having some issues with the resizable part since it takes in two values:

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font as tkfont

class Manifold(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self) #container = stack of frames; one on top is visible
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F,geometry,title in zip((StartPage,PageOne,PageTwo,PageThree),
                                ("532x279","532x279","254x279","299x620"),
                                ("","Experimental Data","Orientation Distribution","Manifold Embedding"),
                                ((False,False),(False,False),(True,True),(True,True))):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[page_name] = (frame,geometry,title,(option1,option2)) #puts all pages in stacked order
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.show_frame("StartPage")

def show_frame(self, page_name): #show a frame for the given page name
    frame, geometry, title = self.frames[page_name]
    self.update_idletasks()
    self.geometry(geometry) #changes between window sizes
    tk.Tk.wm_title(self, title) #window heading
###UNKNOWN:
    self.resizable(*options)
###########       
    frame.tkraise() #raises window to top

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Manifold()
    app.mainloop()
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is some of the top code cut off/ misindented? And are you encountering an Exception? A stack trace, or comparison between actual and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: My advice is, never make a GUI non-resizable. Users should have control over their windows.

Comment: It seems like all these attributes - size, title, resizeable - should be attributes of the classes themselves. Why are you passing them in rather than making them attributes of each page?

Comment: @BryanOakley hmm... good advice, something to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close. Try this:

```
    self.frames = {}
    for F,geometry,title,options in zip((StartPage,PageOne,PageTwo,PageThree),
                                ("532x279","532x279","254x279","299x620"),
                                ("","Experimental Data","Orientation Distribution","Manifold Embedding"),
                                ((False,False),(False,False),(True,True),(True,True))):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[page_name] = (frame,geometry,title,options) #puts all pages in stacked order
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.show_frame("StartPage")

def show_frame(self, page_name): #show a frame for the given page name
    frame, geometry, title,options = self.frames[page_name]
    self.geometry(geometry) #changes between window sizes
    self.title(title) #window heading
    self.resizable(*options)
###########       
    frame.tkraise() #raises window to top
```

Assuming this is a subclass of `Tk()`.

`update_idletasks` should not be needed (it's very rarely used).

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot neater to put those options in each Frame's `tkraise()` method. In order to do that you would need a hook to the root (the Tk() instance). Since you've obfuscated that somewhat with your "container" Frame (why?) you need to be sure to pass the root instance along. A simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class BigWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        tk.Button(self, text='go to\nsmall window', command=lambda: master.show_frame(SmallWindow)).pack()

    def tkraise(self):
        self.master.title('Big Window')
        self.master.geometry('600x600')
        self.master.resizable(True, True)
        tk.Frame.tkraise(self) # raise this Frame

class SmallWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        tk.Button(self, text='go to\nbig window', command=lambda: master.show_frame(BigWindow)).pack()

    def tkraise(self):
        self.master.title('Small Window')
        self.master.geometry('200x200')
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        tk.Frame.tkraise(self)

class Manifold(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (SmallWindow, BigWindow):
            frame = F(self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(SmallWindow)

    def show_frame(self, page): #show a frame for the given page
        self.frames[page].tkraise()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Manifold()
    app.mainloop()
```

You could make this even cleaner by making a base class for all your other frames to inherit from, and then just setting some variables:

```
import tkinter as tk

class AutoSizeFrame(tk.Frame):
    def tkraise(self):
        self.master.title(self.title)
        self.master.geometry(self.geometry)
        self.master.resizable(*self.resizemodes)
        tk.Frame.tkraise(self) # raise this Frame

class BigWindow(AutoSizeFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.title = 'Big Window'
        self.geometry = '600x600'
        self.resizemodes = (True, True)

        tk.Button(self, text='go to\nsmall window', command=lambda: master.show_frame(SmallWindow)).pack()

class SmallWindow(AutoSizeFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.title = 'Small Window'
        self.geometry = '200x200'
        self.resizemodes = (False, False)

        tk.Button(self, text='go to\nbig window', command=lambda: master.show_frame(BigWindow)).pack()

class Manifold(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (SmallWindow, BigWindow):
            frame = F(self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(SmallWindow)

    def show_frame(self, page): #show a frame for the given page
        self.frames[page].tkraise()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Manifold()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: wow! thank you so much for your advice!!  this is truly helpful